# Connect external hard drive to Ubuntu

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, windows-xp

I have an NTFS external hard drive that contains only Windows XP data. How do I connect it to Ubuntu?

Comment: Did You tried to just plug it in? Ubuntu sees Windows partitions (either NTFS or FAT).

Answer (score 1):

External hard drives are normally plug and play in Ubuntu. Just insert the external hard drive cable and turn the external hard drive on, and it will be mounted automatically. For that matter you can also mount an *internal* hard drive in a external hard drive enclosure and it will normally be mounted automatically in Ubuntu too, which is useful for accessing data or doing data recovery on an internal hard drive from a different computer.

All currently supported versions of Ubuntu support the NTFS and FAT filesystems out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As danijelc and karel have mentioned, you can just plug and play with most hard drives. If the hard drive does not appear on your desktop, you can try running the following

```
sudo mkdir /media/hdd
sudo mount /dev/<your device> /media/hdd
```

where `<your device>` is most likely `/dev/sdb1` or similar.